# Localizable string not found in strings table in iOS 9

Tags: ios, ios9, nslocalizedstring

I work in a company that has an app in production with a localization bug in iOS 9 only. The **app shows the key of the localized strings**, not the values. Apparently, it can't found the corresponding string in the table. **On iOS 8, the app works fine**.

I don't know the source code well, but I made sure the file Localization.strings is there, in the right bundle, with the correct target. I'm pretty confident the resource is there, because of tests I made and mostly because the strings are there in iOS 8!

I looked for changes in APIs in iOS 9 but couldn't find anything related to my issue. I also ran the `plutil` command on all the `.strings` files and I got OK for all of them.

Any clue as to where to look?

Comment: Have you tried the NSBundle method for getting localized strings, to see if the behavior is different?

Comment: To be sure, you mean `[[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:value:table:]` as opposed to the macro `NSLocalizedString(key, comment)` ? If so, yes I did. It's not working either.

Comment: That is the method.  Have you confirmed that the strings file is present in the bundle in the simulator?  You should be able to print the bundle path to the console and then go inspect it.  There should be .lproj folders directly in the bundle path folder that contain your strings files.

Comment: `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Localizable" ofType:@"strings"]` returns nil, but if I enumerate all files in the bundle, I can see `Localizable.strings` inside `*.lproj`. I did inspect the bundle via the Finder and I can also see it there.

Comment: It's also strange that iOS 8 can see the file and retrieve the correct value for the key.

Comment: Yeah, that is strange.  I would probably close the project, go into the Projects window, delete the derived data for the project, open it again, and cross my fingers.

Comment: It didn't work either. (Also: the chat feature is blocked by the network here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the app was using multiple Localization.strings file for specific localizations (tweaking the bundle and Localization system). Deleting all those files (with duplicated names) and replacing it with another system (a plist file, mainly) made it work correctly.

It seems obvious there was a conflicting name issue here, but I'm still puzzled by the fact that it worked with older iOS (8 and under).